# why apache downloads text file instead of displaying on browser

Tags: apache

apache downloads text file instead of displaying on browser. This happens only if the owner of the file is not the apache user.

I'm trying to open the alis /log in apache:

```
Alias /log "/home/log/"
<Directory /home/log/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all  
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

It could be worth mentioning that file extensions are .log example: filename.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

needed to add this line in httpd.conf

```
AddType text/plain .js .sh .txt .log
```

I tackled this before but failed because I forgot to add the .log
from this link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20171224215131/https://marcel.zurreck.com/nginx-apache-force-the-browser-to-show-a-file-instead-of-downloading

Comment: Or mods-enabled/mime.conf